# access database relationships

Tags: ms-access-2007, relationships

I am using access 2007. I made a database called holiday which has 3 tables namely:

```
client - this has all the client information
flight - this stores flight information
cruise - this stores cruiser information
```

what I'm thinking of doing, is to make a relationship between these three tables. I just thought myself "relationships" from google and from what I understand is that I should use a one-to-many relationship.

I did that each table has a column called customerID where the client table has it as a primary key and the others as  foreign-key. What I want to know is how do I link up the tables so that when I enter information onto the client table both flight and cruise should open as subselection because currently only one is opening and I don't know how to enter the other?

Comment: Drag the Primary Key from one table to the Foreign Key in the other table, using the Query Explorer.

Comment: i just saw all my spelling mistake i apologise

Comment: i did that... what i currently have in the relationship layout is 3 tables and both flight and cruise are foreign keys connected to the 1 primary key in the client table. Yet still when i open the client table to input data only flight opens and not cruise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 ways to create a relationship between tables.

One is permanently with the Relationships Window (under Database Tools in Access 2010). Drag from a field in one table to a field in an other table. Then double click on the line (join) to edit the join type.

The other is to do this temporarily in A Query Builder window. Then you create the join the same way as above.  This join is only set in this query only, or anything else based on this query.

OK, now that you them joined, what are your plans. One way is to create a form for editing the customer info, along with two sub-forms for editing the flight & cruise info.

Good luck

Comment: yes exactly started my project in c# now and its all working out thank you so much :)